Error clrscr() en C++
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<graphics.h>
#include<dos.h>

void main()
{
  clrscr();
  int gd=DETECT,gm;
  initgraph(&gd,&gm,"C:\\tc\\bgi");

  for (int i=0;i<500;i++)
  {
    /***CAR BODY ******/
    line(50+i,370,90+i,370);
    arc(110+i,370,0,180,20);
    line(130+i,370,220+i,370);
    arc(240+i,370,0,180,20);
    line(260+i,370,300+i,370);
    line(300+i,370,300+i,350);
    line(300+i,350,240+i,330);
    line(240+i,330,200+i,300);
    line(200+i,300,110+i,300);
    line(110+i,300,80+i,330);
    line(80+i,330,50+i,340);
    line(50+i,340,50+i,370);

    /***CAR Windows***/
    line(165+i,305,165+i,330);
    line(165+i,330,230+i,330);
    line(230+i,330,195+i,305);
    line(195+i,305,165+i,305);

    line(160+i,305,160+i,330);
    line(160+i,330,95+i,330);
    line(95+i,330,120+i,305);
    line(120+i,305,160+i,305);

    /**Wheels**/
    circle(110+i,370,17);
    circle(240+i,370,17);

    delay(10);
    cleardevice();

    line(0,390,639,390);  //ROAD
  }

  getch();
}

Al intentar compilar y ejecutar me sale un error:

'clrscr was not declarated in the scope '

He de aclarar, que hace poco me daba error el include graphics pero ya lo arregle y ahora me da error esto de clrscr y me tiene cansado porque cada cosa que intento hacer siempre tengo problemas ¿a qué se puede deber? y ¿cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Mi IDE es DEV C++ 5.11


Las funciones clrscr() en initgraph() sirven para compiladores borland antiguos, no son funciones estándar de c. Podrías buscar algo como esto: https://openbgi.sourceforge.net/

¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? error al poner clrscr ();
